# Confused about eigenvetor

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to find the eigenvectors of a matrix with first row of (1 1) and second row of (1 -1).

Got the eigenvalues to be $\sqrt 2$ and $-\sqrt 2$. When I tried however to find the eigenvector of $\sqrt 2$ for arbitrary column vector $(x_1, x_2)$, I got two equations:

1. $(1-\sqrt2)x_1+x_2=0$
2. $x_1+(-1-\sqrt2)x_2=0$

So from 1. we get that $x_2=(-1+\sqrt2)x_1$, but from 2. we get that $x_2=\frac {1}{1+\sqrt2}x_1$. Is there anything wrong here?

**edit**: I got it! Multiply 2. with $\frac {1-\sqrt2}{1-\sqrt2}$.

Sorry for wasting any of your time!

Comment: There isn't.${}$

Comment: Yeah, thank you anyways! See my edit

Comment: Feel free to delete your question.

Comment: how can i delete it?

Comment: There should be delete button between *close* and *flag*. If there isn't, you can flag the question for moderator attention and request its deletion.